# How to write logs in serilog to same path on Linux and WIndows?

Tags: .net-core, serilog

I have an app that configures Serilog via [appsettings.json](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration) file, i develop the app on windows but it is deployed to linux.
How can i write logs to a relative directory Logs/logfile.log?

Is just changing the appsettings.json at deployment folder a good option?

right now this is the config i am using:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.MSSQLServer" ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {SourceContext} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.SystemConsoleTheme::Grayscale, Serilog.Sinks.Console"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs\\log-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 5
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is the following:

1. Create two appsettings files one should be the default and the second one appsettings.Linux.json
   [image]
2. Read the appsettings file depending on which OS the application is running.

   ```
   var env = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux) ?
   "Linux" : "Windows";
   Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
           .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", true)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables()
           .Build();
   ```
3. Set different values for the logger in the appsettings.Linux.json.
   For Windows:

   "Args": {
         "path": "Logs\log-.log",
         "rollingInterval": "Day",
         "retainedFileCountLimit": 5
       }

For Linux:

```
 "Args": {
          "path": "/var/log/appname",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 5
        }
```